# Unable to user an ORDER BY clause in a window function with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I've got a query that works fine without the `ORDER BY` clause in the window function:

```
select
"TABLE_NAME",
"DENSITY",
"NUM_DISTINCT",
ROWNUM,
median(DENSITY) OVER (PARTITION BY table_name )
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS a
where 1=1
and owner = 'SYS'
and table_name='CARRY'
and "NUM_DISTINCT" < 1000
and DENSITY < 1
AND num_nulls = 0
```

But I definitely need this `order by` clause to get the data in the format I need it. If I add the `order by`, I get this weird error message:

```
ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here
30487. 00000 -  "ORDER BY not allowed here"
*Cause:    DISTINCT functions and RATIO_TO_REPORT cannot have an ORDER BY
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 47
```

Here's the full SQL with the order by:

```
select
"TABLE_NAME",
"DENSITY",
"NUM_DISTINCT",
ROWNUM,
median(DENSITY) OVER (PARTITION BY table_name ORDER BY "DENSITY")
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS a
where 1=1
and owner = 'DEANZA'
and table_name='CARRIER_A'
and "NUM_DISTINCT" < 1000
and DENSITY < 1
AND num_nulls = 0
```

Comment: No, you definitely don't need to use ORDER BY in the MEDIAN(...) function. Do you understand what MEDIAN does? What do you need - for the third row you need the median density just of the first three density values, then for the tenth row - the median of the first ten density values, etc. ? What might you need that for?

Comment: Put the `ORDER BY DENSITY` at the end of the query, not in the `MEDIAN` calculation. You can't use `ORDER BY` in the `MEDIAN` analytic function - and when you do use `ORDER BY` in an analytic function that allows it, it has nothing to do with sorting your results.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Sample data and desired results can be a big help in communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions111.htm#SQLRF06315), for `MEDIAN` you cannot use `ORDER BY` in its `OVER` clause.

`MEDIAN` will take a numeric or datetime value and returns the middle value or an interpolated value that would be the middle value once the values are **sorted**. So there is no need to use `ORDER BY` anyway.

Comment: Do you understand what ORDER BY does in an analytic function? It has little to do with ordering the whole partition.

Comment: Yes, I guess the OP thinks that MEDIAN won't sort the data first.

Comment: `order by` would have been useful for windowing with `rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding` for example.